# SQL server php login script

Tags: php, sql-server

I have created the script to validate my login system but i am having trouble figuring out how to make it specifically log in to my `sqlserver` account to my specific work space my log in script so far goes as the following

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"])){
        header("location:../../login.html");
    }

    $username = $_POST['txt_username'];
    $user_id = $_POST['txt_password'];


    mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die("No Server Found");

    mysql_select_db($schema) or die("No Connection");

?>
```

Comment: this isn't actually connecting to the database to allow me to fetch login details

Comment: Where is your query to check username and password?

Comment: please let me know whether you are using Microsoft SQL server or Mysql database. If you are using SQL server. Follow the below coding // Create a link to MSSQL
$link = mssql_connect('KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS', 'root', 'pass');

// Select the database 'php'
mssql_select_db('database1', $link);

Comment: SQL server also that is what i cant seem to find out about i have done research but it all seems to come back to 1 bit of code that i cant figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Below is the code for connecting to a MSSQL Server database

```
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); 

//declare the SQL statement that will query the database
$query = "SELECT id, name, year ";
$query .= "FROM cars ";
$query .= "WHERE name='BMW'"; 

//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mssql_query($query);

$numRows = mssql_num_rows($result); 
echo "<h1>" . $numRows . " Row" . ($numRows == 1 ? "" : "s") . " Returned </h1>"; 

//display the results 
while($row = mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo "<li>" . $row["id"] . $row["name"] . $row["year"] . "</li>";
}
//close the connection
mssql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

**Connect with a DSN**

[ODBC Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.uodbc.php)

**DSN** stands for '**Data Source Name**'. It is an easy way to assign useful and easily rememberable names to data sources which may not be limited to databases alone.

In the example below we will show you how to connect with a DSN to a MSSQL Server database called 'examples'  and retrieve all the records from the table 'cars'.

```
<?php 

//connect to a DSN "myDSN" 
$conn = odbc_connect('myDSN','',''); 

if ($conn) 
{ 
  //the SQL statement that will query the database 
  $query = "select * from cars"; 
  //perform the query 
  $result=odbc_exec($conn, $query); 

  echo "<table border=\"1\"><tr>"; 

  //print field name 
  $colName = odbc_num_fields($result); 
  for ($j=1; $j<= $colName; $j++) 
  {  
    echo "<th>"; 
    echo odbc_field_name ($result, $j ); 
    echo "</th>"; 
  } 

  //fetch tha data from the database 
  while(odbc_fetch_row($result)) 
  { 
    echo "<tr>"; 
    for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($result);$i++) 
    { 
      echo "<td>"; 
      echo odbc_result($result,$i); 
      echo "</td>"; 
    } 
    echo "</tr>"; 
  } 

  echo "</td> </tr>"; 
  echo "</table >"; 

  //close the connection 
  odbc_close ($conn); 
} 
else echo "odbc not connected"; 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this was a great help.